# How to write a mssql database with Python's SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, sqlalchemy

Does anyone know a tutorial for making a MSSql database from python using SQLAlchemy. The reason for using MSsql is that some of my co-workers prefer Excel as the way to access the data.

I looked around but I could not find a simple example for a newcommer like me

Any advise would be gratefully acknoledged.
Allan

Answer (score 0):

You can download SQL Server 2012 Express. It installs pretty easy, you won't even need Python to set it up.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

It can import Flat files (such as Text), Excel, and Access files very easily.

Just make sure you choose the right version - 32 or 64 bit.

Here's a YouTube video on [how to import an Excel file into SQL Server](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1vqhYlwcyA).

Comment: From there, it's fairly easy to just use the database and you can connect your Python environment to that database.

Comment: However, if you just want to install SQLAlchemy, the website has a good start. 

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/intro.html